# Is there a Linux utility to return an error code for a particular input?

Tags: linux, shell

I'm running Puppet, and I need to run one of the defined `exec` commands only if a line does not exist in the output from a different command.  I can set up a contingency with a `unless` clause (which will run the command *unless* another command returns exit code `0`) or with a `onlyif` clause (which will run a command *only* if another command returns exit code `0`).

Is there a standard Linux command which will verify a particular substring exists in the input, and return an exit code otherwise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would [grep](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) do what you want ?

In particular

```
grep -q something somefile
```

will exit with status 0 if something was in somefile and 1 if not.

The somefile can be a pipe too

```
somecommand | grep -q something
```

will exit with status 0 if the output from somecommand contains something.

Comment: The standard shell idiom is to `if somecommand | grep -q expected ; then it-was-there ; else scream-it-was-not-there ; fi`

Comment: @Matt: `grep -q` [conforms to POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/grep.html).  (A little late, but just in case someone else stumbles across this.)

Comment: So it does.. I'm struggling to remember where I picked up that impression now.  I think it was Solaris 9's standard `grep`. Everything else seems to support it. Thanks! Erroneous comment baleeted.